# remove this string ^[[38;1H^[[K^[[7m71%^[[27m^[[38;1H^[[38;1H^[[K

Tags: text, vi

I am trying to remove from a text file the following string as displayed by vim

> ^[[38;1H^[[K^[[7m71%^[[27m^[[38;1H^[[38;1H^[[K

in this text files i have 7m1000 entries
meaning

> ^[[38;1H^[[K^[[7m71%^[[27m^[[38;1H^[[38;1H^[[K
>   ^[[38;1H^[[K^[[7m72%^[[27m^[[38;1H^[[38;1H^[[K
>   ^[[38;1H^[[K^[[7m73%^[[27m^[[38;1H^[[38;1H^[[K ...
>   ^[[38;1H^[[K^[[7m1000%^[[27m^[[38;1H^[[38;1H^[[K

I tried with cat/grep/sed..

I tried with the following script

```
def Process(data):
 text = data.split()[0]
 #print repr(text)
 text = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
 data.split()[0]= text
 return data
```

Producing

```
:python Clo.py
IP:     138.42.153.194->10.132.136.42, protocol 6, [38;1H[K[7m86%[27m[38;1H[38;1H[KTCP:    sport 3389, dport 58187, seq 978549389, ack 33554488, flags 0x0018 ( ACK PSH), urgent data 0, Flow fastpath, session 911218, wqe index 487973 packet 0x0x80000000416988e6,  Packet info: len 107 port 17 interface 17 vsys 0, Packet from interface 256 forwarded to DP0 for tunnel encap
```

would it be possible to remove ["'\x1b[38;1H\x1b[K\x1b[7m######%\x1b[27m\x1b[38;1H\x1b[38;1H\x1b[KTCP:]  directly from VI?

Comment: `being trying with cat/grep/sed/` yes. do that. if you have trouble with those commands, show what you tried exactly. One thing to note is that what vim shows may not be the actual characters

Comment: Thanks, TCP:  when doing cat for example the line just jumps around  sport 3389, dport 58187, seq 978549389, ack 33554488,
[~/Desktop]| grep 38
:P:     138.42.153.194->10.132.136.42, protocol 6
TCP:    sport 3389, dport 58187, seq 978436348, ack 33554488,
IP:     138.42.153.194->10.132.136.42, protocol 6

Comment: I have no idea, but last time I was stuck trying to do something in a text editor I wrote a script to do that...

Comment: "but no luck" is hardly a scientific problem statement.

Comment: :) correct statement fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for me was

:%s/^[.*^[//g

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem